# Need to purge one third of data from a table having 1.5 TB data

Tags: database, oracle, sql-delete, purge

Have a oracle table with almost 1.5 TB data in it. Need to purge atleast 0.5 TB data from it. This is a Production table, and have significant number of write commands running on it. What is the best way and fastest way to purge this data.

Comment: If you can upgrade to 12.2 then you can convert a non-partitioned table to a partitioned one in [a single DDL command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877).

Answer (score 2):

"Purge" = "remove" = "delete", I presume.

You have several options; here are some of them:

- Is the table partitioned? I guess not; otherwise, you'd just `truncate` (or `drop`) partitions you don't need any more, and it would be *fast*

  - can you partition it now?
- Another option is to literally `delete` those rows. It'll create a large *undo*.

  - this option is probably quite slow
- Or, use CTAS (Create Table As Select) and create a new table with rows you'd want to keep; then truncate (or, if you can afford it, drop) the original table and move rows back (or, if you dropped it, rename newly created table to the old, original name). Depending on foreign key constraints, that might not be that simple.

  - this one takes additional space on a disk. Do you have it? What about constraints?
- Or, delete rows in *chunks*, using loop in a PL/SQL procedure. In order to save some undo space, commit within a loop (not too frequently, though). ORA-01555 (*snapshot too old*) might appear

  - deleting piece-by-piece is OK if you aren't worried about "all or nothing". What if delete fails? Will it affect anything else? How?

Which one is *the best*? That's a *million dollars question*, and I don't have an answer to it. If possible, import that table into your testing environment and ... well, *test* those options. Testing in production isn't recommended, right?

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem at work. Our plan of attack is to do an online redefinition to partition the table. Once that is done, the relevant partitions can be dropped.

We are currently setting up a copy of the database on a test machine to test the approach.